# Trying to convert a string to base64 in Jmeter not working

Tags: jmeter

have the following concatenate string "username:encode password", and encoded it to to base 64. And I am getting following error,

```
2023-06-28 14:27:50,613 ERROR o.a.j.e.JSR223PostProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PostProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Base64Encoder for class: Script72
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:93) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.extractor.JSR223PostProcessor.process(JSR223PostProcessor.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPostProcessors(JMeterThread.java:968) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:585) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.5]
```

Code base :

```
import com.org.util.Crypto;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

def password = 'passc0de';
def encPassword = Crypto.encodeMD5Base64(password);
def authCode = 'testUser:'+encPassword;

String auth_token = authCode.toString();
log.info('AuthToken -------------->'+auth_token)
String auth_token_encoded = Base64Encoder.encode(auth_token) as String();
log.info('-------------->'+auth_token_encoded)
```

From the response when I encode it online I can see the correct value;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that compiler is not able to find your `Base64Encoder` class.

You need to add necessary [`import` statement](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_imports) like you did for `com.org.util.Crypto`

In general Groovy has [built-in Base64 support](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-base64-encoding.html) so you don't need any extra libraries:

[image]

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks dmitri, although your gif file has the solution of my question